# GDK signal, keypress, and key masks

Tags: c, gtk, signals, keyboard-shortcuts, gdk

I am trying to catch user key press Ctrl+d on a GUI window to quit. My code looks like this:

```
static gboolean
callback(GtkWidget   *widget,
         GdkEventKey *event,
         gpointer    data)
{
    if(event->state == GDK_CONTROL_MASK && event->keyval == 'd')
        gtk_main_quit();

    return FASLE;
}
```

This works on my laptop(Ubuntu 11.04, gcc 4.5.2, libgtk 2.24.4). But when I do the same thing on a newer system(Ubuntu 12.10, gcc 4.7.2, libgtk 2.24.13), it doesn't work.

I added `g_print("%u\n", event->state);` before the `if` statement, it shows that when I press `Ctrl`, the `event->state` is 20 instead of 4 or 1 << 2 in the documentation. If I change the `GDK_CONTROL_MASK` to 20, it works on the newer system but not the old one. Someone please tell me why this happen and how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event->state` is a [bitmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array), which means that a value of 20 doesn't mean "20 instead of 4", but "4 and 16 at the same time". According to the headers, the value 16 (`1 << 4`) corresponds to the `MOD2` modifier, which might correspond to the <kbd>fn</kbd> key present on laptops.

A simple fix is to use the `&` operator to check for control while ignoring other modifiers:

```
    if (event->state & GDK_CONTROL_MASK && event->keyval == 'd')
```

which will work on both systems.

Comment: MOD2 is num lock on many systems.  So it makes sense to mask that out.  But only checking if CONTROL is set means it will also treat Ctrl+Alt+D, Ctrl+Shift+D etc. as Ctrl+D, which isn't ideal either.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `state` also includes modifiers like Caps Lock and Num Lock.

The solution is documented at https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/checklist-modifiers.html:

Use `gtk_accelerator_get_default_mod_mask()` to get a bitmap of the modifiers that are also accelerator keys (Control, Alt, Shift, Super, Hyper, and Meta), then bitwise and the event state, e.g.:

```
GdkModifierType accel_mask = gtk_accelerator_get_default_mod_mask ();

if (event->state & accel_mask == GDK_CONTROL_MASK && event->keyval == 'd')
    ...
```