# Listen to Control + mouse wheel scroll event in Python GTK3

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I am building a Python GTK application and I need to listen to the "Ctrl+Mouse wheel" event. I want to implement "zoom" feature in Webview. Do I need to setup an accelerator? If yes, what is the key code for mouse wheel?

There isn't really much documentation on these topics.

Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it happens many times, After posting in SO I found the solution :)

Here it is:

**Listen the "scroll event" on webview:**

```
 self.connect('scroll-event', self.on_scroll)
```

**Signal handler**

```
 def on_scroll(self, widget, event):
    """ handles on scroll event"""

   # Handles zoom in / zoom out on Ctrl+mouse wheel
   accel_mask = Gtk.accelerator_get_default_mod_mask()
   if event.state & accel_mask == Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK:
     direction = event.get_scroll_deltas()[2]
     if direction > 0:  # scrolling down -> zoom out
        self.set_zoom_level(self.get_zoom_level() - 0.1)
     else:
        self.set_zoom_level(self.get_zoom_level() + 0.1)
```

Reference: [GDK signal, keypress, and key masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226043/gdk-signal-keypress-and-key-masks)

Comment: It's correct and you can mark it as answer. However, in some cases you should call [`Gtk.Widget.add_events()`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.add_events) first.